# "Do not wrap after single annotation" analogue for Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am using ButterKnife in my project and with Java I have enabled "Do not wrap after single annotation" code style setting to prevent auto formatting annotations in two lines.

But I can't find such option for Kotlin. Does anybody know any analogue or it was simply renamed?

I am using Android Studio 3.1.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. If you don't want Android Studio automatically wrap your annotations in two lines use this:

1. Go to Android Studio's Settings.
2. Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin.
3. Select "Wrapping and Braces" tab.
4. Find "Property annotations" position and set "Do not wrap" option.
5. That is all!

[image]

Comment: This turns off annotation wrapping entirely. The question was about the "Do not wrap after single annotation" option, which is not the same.

Comment: Maybe I did not correctly express my wish, but I tried to achieve just this result.

Answer (score 1):

This option is currently (as of version 1.2.30) unsupported for Kotlin. You're welcome to file a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT requesting to add the support.

Comment: [KT-26796: Support "Do not wrap after single annotation" option for Kotlin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26796)